# PHP5 not running under IIS 6

Tags: php, iis, iis-6, php5

I have a Windows Server 2003 VPS running IIS 6 and .NET Framework 4 and PHP.
I have a client that needs to run a custom PHP application. But their files wouldn't run as PHP script.
I run Wordpress on other websites fine.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, could you provide some info on what actually happens when you try execute their PHP scripts ?
Without more info this is all i can suggest:

Add a file called "test.php" to a site containing the following

`<?php
phpinfo();
?>`

when you try access the file via
 `http://yourdomain/location/to/test.php`

**does it show you exactly what is in the file ?**

you need to add php5.dll extention to IIS

**does it ask you to download the file ?**

same as above.

**does it print out a phpinfo page ?**

if the phpinfo page prints out correctly, check if your clients php files use short open tags eg.

`<?
phpinfo();
?>`

if so you may just need to enable that in your php.ini

I hope this is clear and helps.

Dylan.

Comment: +1 - 9 times out of 10 that I've seen this, it's because they were using short tags and short tags weren't enabled on the server.